# Uncertainty of waves

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, mathematical-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Here in the pictures I have written about some question I have been thinking about a long time, what do you think?

Link to the chapter I am talking about:
[http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/GaborLocalization.pdf](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Ematilde/GaborLocalization.pdf)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you type up your question, including as pictures only the necessary figures?

Comment: You've inserted a large image.  Please rewrite this so that there is no text in images (unless the text is a caption from a publication).    Using an image makes the question unsearchable.